# Excel Links and Drop-Down Menus

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet with two sheets: Authors and Books.

In Authors, there is an "ID" column, where each cell contain a UUID.

In Books, I have "Author" column, where each cell contains a UUID of an author.

Questions:

1. In Books, how would I make each Author cell a hyper link to the corresponding Author row?
2. In Books, how would I make each Author cell have a drop-down menu with Author options, instead of allowing the user to type in the cell?

Example:

```
AUTHORS
+-----+--------+
| ID  | NAME   |
+-----+--------+
| 134 | ABC    |
| 135 | XYZ    |
+-----+--------+

BOOKS
+--------+--------+
| TITLE  | AUTHOR |
+--------+--------+
| Book1  | 134    |
| Book2  | 134    |
| Book3  | 135    |
+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Data validation maybe? It would be helpful to see sample data and the expected result

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I added an example.

Comment: Drop down list: start here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/video-create-and-manage-drop-down-lists-28db87b6-725f-49d7-9b29-ab4bc56cefc2

Comment: Hyperlink: start here - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/work-with-links-in-excel-7fc80d8d-68f9-482f-ab01-584c44d72b3e#:~:text=On%20a%20worksheet%2C%20select%20the,use%20to%20represent%20the%20link.

Comment: @Alon did you manage?